# How to I add a constant into a with block?

Tags: oracle

In a with block, I can define function and query, I would like to define a constant too that I can  reuse after.

the following code works.

```
WITH
    FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN a + 1;
    END;
    b(v) AS (SELECT column_value FROM sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3)) 

SELECT a (v) FROM  b;
```

but this doesn't work.

```
WITH
    c integer:=1;
    FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
        RETURN INTEGER
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN a + 1;
    END;
    b(v) AS (SELECT column_value FROM sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3)) 

SELECT a (v) FROM  b;
```

> [Error] Execution (14: 20): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I know that I can create another query in the with block:
`select 1 c from dual`

But it doesn't look pretty if I have a lot of constants.

Is there  a way to add constant in a with block?

Answer (score 1):

Add another subquery factoring clause with exactly one row and define all the constants in there and then `CROSS JOIN` it to your other queries:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
  RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN a + 1;
END;
constants (c1, c2, c3, c4) AS (
  SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4 FROM DUAL
),
b(v) AS (
  SELECT column_value FROM sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3)
) 
SELECT a(v), c.*
FROM   b
       CROSS JOIN constants c;
```

Or, you could declare a function for each constant:

```sql
WITH FUNCTION a (a IN INTEGER)
  RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN a + 1;
END;
FUNCTION c1 RETURN INTEGER IS BEGIN RETURN 1; END;
FUNCTION c2 RETURN INTEGER IS BEGIN RETURN 2; END;
FUNCTION c3 RETURN INTEGER IS BEGIN RETURN 3; END;
FUNCTION c4 RETURN INTEGER IS BEGIN RETURN 4; END;
b(v) AS (
  SELECT column_value FROM sys.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,2,3)
) 
SELECT a(v), c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM   b;
```

*(However, using functions may introduce a performance overhead with repeated context-switches between SQL and PL/SQL scopes. Personally, I would use the first option.)*

Which both output:

> | A(V) | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
> | 4 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7750c95fd8f453636ec4adab50a9126a)*